# Share directory between users

Tags: permissions

I am trying to share a directory between two users. The directory is at `/reports`. I have created a group (`addgroup reports`), changed the group of the directory, changed the permissions of `/reports` to allow full access to groups and added the two users to that groups by the following:

```
mkdir /reports
addgroup reports
chgrp -R reports /reports
chmod -R 770 /reports  
usermod -a -G reports user1
usermod -a -G reports user2
```

As user1, running the following, I get a permission denied error.

```
 touch /reports/foo.txt
```

Running `groups user1` does not show `reports` group, but the mapping is there in `/etc/group`

but I still get a permission denied error.

Comment: Btw: the Debian/Ubuntu-way of doing the group membership adjustments is: `adduser user1 reports && adduser user2 reports` ... it's a way more convenient wrapper around `usermod`. Using the old way is by no means wrong, however.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like logging out and logging in again resolved the issue.

Comment: That's right. You just discovered that group membership requires that the user log in. Had you tried it on another terminal which wasn't logged in before, the result would have been the same.

Comment: I tried that, but I was on tmux, so I created new shells, and creating new windows doesn't count as `logging in` it seems.